# Boundary in Powell method Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, minimize, boundary

Let's minimise the function

```
f =lambda x: (x+1)**2
```

using Powell method in scipy

If we use

`scipy.optimize.minimize(f, 1, method='Powell', bounds=None)`

the return is

```
   direc: array([[1.]])
     fun: array(0.)
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 20
     nit: 2
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array(-1.)
```

i.e. the minimum is at -1 as it should. If we provide the bounds

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(f, 1, method='Powell', bounds=[(0,2)])
```

the return is again

```
   direc: array([[1.]])
     fun: array(0.)
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 20
     nit: 2
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array(-1.)
```

which is now WRONG! The correct answer should be 0. It is like if the bounds are not taken int account. I am using scipy '1.4.1' and python 3.7.6.
Someone has any clue?

Comment: It is very helpful! Sorry I am "new" to stack overflow.. and didn't know how to accept it.. thx again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With scipy 1.4.x the Powell method cannot handle constraints nor bounds, as you can see [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/maintenance/1.4.x/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py#L519). Updating to scipy 1.5.x, it can handle bounds, see [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/maintenance/1.5.x/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py#L531):

```
In [11]: scipy.optimize.minimize(f, x0=1.0, method='Powell', bounds=[(0.0,2.0)])
Out[11]:
   direc: array([[1.64428414e-08]])
     fun: array(1.)
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 103
     nit: 2
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([2.44756652e-12])
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that I have noticed as well that the Powell method tends to explore out of bounds parameters.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31786108)